# How to create symlink on heroku server?

Tags: heroku, symlink

My rails app is on heroku server.
I need to create symlink for public folder.

How to create symlink on heroku server?

Thanks!

Comment: It seems like the [Ephemeral Filesystem][1] would allow you to do this.  I'm working on a solution and will report back if I find one.

  [1]: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dyno-isolation#ephemeral_filesystem

Comment: Typically you'd tweak the buildpack configuration instead.

Comment: Hey, did you solve this? I really need to do this on my heroku container

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using the Ephemeral Filesystem, but only if you're using the Cedar stack (currently in beta at the time of this writing).  More info on Heroku's stacks:  http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/stack

Just simply make a symlink like you normally would -- but you should also expect it to not exist at boot time.

Comment: doesn't answer the question. HOW do you use the "Ephemeral Filesystem" (what ever that is) to do this?

Comment: Edited to address CpILL's comment.